# How to duplicate elements in a js array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Whats the easiest way (with "native" javascript) to duplicate every element in a javascript array?

The order *matters*.

For example:

```
a = [2, 3, 1, 4]
// do something with a
a
// a is now [2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Not preferred/recommended/reliable but regex can also be used. `a = a.join(',').replace(/(\d+)/g, "$1,$1").split(',').map(Number);`

Comment: @Tushar Nice idea. However, as you already assumed, I'm looking for a generic solution that also works with arrays of strings that might even contain commas...

Comment: **The top answers to this question seem to be games of complexity code golf**. Don't use reduce, the intent is super unclear. Sometimes a for loop is the correct answer guys, sorry.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I came up with something similar to [tymeJV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1686485/tymejv)'s answer

```
[2, 3, 1, 4].reduce(function (res, current, index, array) {
    return res.concat([current, current]);
}, []);
```

Comment: I don't understand why the two last parameters (`index`, `array`) are needed if I don't see them used. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: How to duplicate it 10 times?

Comment: `[2,3,1,4].reduce((a,i)=>a.concat(i,i),[])` is a lot easier to read or `a.concat(Array(10).fill(i))`, or map if i is an an object and you need clones

Answer (score 34):

Basically you can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) in ES19

```js
a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
a.flatMap(i => [i,i]); // [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Also you can customize the repetitions number like this:

```js
a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const dublicateItems = (arr, numberOfRepetitions) => 
    arr.flatMap(i => Array.from({ length: numberOfRepetitions }).fill(i));

dublicateItems(a, 3);
```

*My reply to the comment below by @user120242*
**why so complicated? a.flatMap(i => Array(n).fill(i))** [find it here](https://www.zeyadetman.com/posts/another-way-to-write-your-javascript#1-generate-an-array-of-sequential-numbers-1-2-3--n)

Comment: You can continue answering on it. Thanks @Kaiido

Comment: why so complicated?  `a.flatMap(i => Array(n).fill(i))`

Comment: @ZeyadEtman You mean ES10 (ES2019)?

Comment: @user120242 please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 17):

Basically:

```
a = [2, 3, 1, 4];
b=[];

for(var i = 0; i< a.length;++i){
  b.push(a[i]);
  b.push(a[i]);
}

a=b;
```

Comment: If anyone wonders which is the best way, I made a benchmark and **this is the fastest** way to duplicate, but if you want to duplicate more than 6 times use nested loops for even more efficient duplication. (Tested on a random array with 100000 elements)

Comment: one can make it even faster if avoid to call to a.length in every step

Comment: @SergeiKovalenko do you have any benchmark on that? Because as far as I know `a.length` has O(1) complexity because array length should be implemented as a constant in JS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850662/time-complexity-of-javascripts-array-length for further info

Comment: @morels, the benchmarks script in the page you provided shows sometimes .length 11 and var 11, but mostly .length 12 and var 10, which is the difference between the calculation and direct access to the value. but there is never .length < var

Comment: Do you have any public source? I'm genuinely interested. I cannot replicate your results because I don't know where data comes from, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

I came across this issue in my application, so I created this function:

```
function duplicateElements(array, times) {
  return array.reduce((res, current) => {
      return res.concat(Array(times).fill(current));
  }, []);
}
```

To use it, simple pass the array, and the number of times you want the elements to be duplicated:

```
duplicateElements([2, 3, 1, 4], 2);
// returns: [2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4]
```

Comment: ES6 version: `return [...res, ...Array(times).fill(current)];`

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you could do:

```
var duplicated = a.map(function(item) {
    return [item, item];
}).reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b) });

//duplicated: [2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Isn't `Map` ES6? In that case there may be compatibility issues with this solution

Comment: map + reduce + concat seems overkill.  Reduce better.

Comment: @EricHerlitz -- `.map` is ES5.

Comment: @EricHerlitz Yes it is, but here, it is `Array.prototype.map`, so no problem as long as it is a standard browser or IE8+

Answer (score 2):

ES6 way of life (based on [axelduch's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2389720/axelduch) answer)

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 1, 4].reduce((res, current) => [...res, current, current], []);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

A very basic snippet by just using loops and push.

It's dynamic function, So you can specify duplicator to duplicate value number of times.

Function name **duplicate**

Syntax: `duplicate (array, duplicator)`

- **Array** array to be passed in the function.
- **duplicator** integer value to be passed to duplicate number of times.

How it works: function takes two parameter array and duplicator, It build new array based on duplicator and return newly built array.

**Snippet**

```
function duplicate(array, duplicator){
        var buildArray = [];
        for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                for(j=0; j<duplicator; j++){
                        buildArray.push(array[i]);
                }
        }
        return buildArray;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var a = [2, 3, 1, 4];
var result = duplicate(a, 2);
console.log(result);
```

Change duplicator value according to your requirement to get desired output.

Reference:

[push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 1):

Just splice a little bit.

```js
var a = [2, 3, 1, 4],
    i = a.length;
while (i--) {
    a.splice(i, 0, a[i]);
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(a, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

These functions may help  see .sort(), .concat()

```
function duplicate(arr) {
    return arr.concat(arr).sort()
} 
console.log(duplicate([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: In question its clearly mentioned **The order matters.**

Answer (score 1):

how 'bout that?

```
for (i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)a.splice(i,0,a[i]);
```

iterating backwards is undervalued, in this case it keeps the index intact ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
0/2  =  0    =  0  |0  =  0
1/2  =  0.5  =  0.5|0  =  0
2/2  =  1    =  1  |0  =  1
3/2  =  1.5  =  1.5|0  =  1
4/2  =  2    =  2  |0  =  2
5/2  =  2.5  =  2.5|0  =  2
6/2  =  3    =  3  |0  =  3
7/2  =  3.5  =  3.5|0  =  3
```

*Treat `|0` as `Math.floor`*

---

In code this could look like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < a.length * 2; i++) {
  a[i] = a[i / 2 | 0]
}
```

Because immutability is preferable, one could do something like this:

```
function repeatItems(a, n) {
  const b = new Array(a.length * n)
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = a[i / n | 0]
  }
  return b
}
```

Unreadable ES6 spaghetti code:

```
const repeatItems = (a, n) => Array.from(Array(a.length * n), (_, i) => a[i / n | 0])
```

Answer (score -2):

Lot of ways to add items to an array as seen above. I have compared it and you can view the performance by yourself in the console.
Whatever is timed goes between the two "console.time"

```
console.clear();

function loopMyArray(){
 var loopArray = new Array(10000);
 for(var i = 0; i < loopArray.length; i++){
   loopArray[i] = i+1;
 }
 console.log(loopArray);
}
console.time('loopMyArray');
loopMyArray();
console.timeEnd('loopMyArray');

function fillArray(){
 let x = 0;
 let filledArray = new Array(10000).fill(null).map(()=> ++x);
 console.log(filledArray);
}

console.time('fillArray');
fillArray();
console.timeEnd('fillArray');

function keyMyArray(){
 let fromKeyArray = Array.from(Array(10000).keys());
 console.log(fromKeyArray);
}
console.time('keyMyArray');
keyMyArray();
console.timeEnd('keyMyArray');

function spreadKeysArray(){
 let spreadArray = [...Array(10000).keys()];
 console.log(spreadArray);
}
console.time('spreadKeysArray');
spreadKeysArray();
console.timeEnd('spreadKeysArray');

console.log(' Start from 1');

function mapKeyArray(){
 //let mapArray = ([...Array(1000).keys()].map(x => x++)); //increment after return
 let mapArray = [...Array(10000).keys()].map(x => ++x);
 console.log(mapArray);
}

console.time('mapKeyArray');
mapKeyArray();
console.timeEnd('mapKeyArray');

function sliceKeyArray(){
 let sliceFirstElementArray = [...Array(10000+1).keys()].slice(1);
 console.log(sliceFirstElementArray);
}
console.time('sliceKeyArray');
sliceKeyArray();
console.timeEnd('sliceKeyArray');

function calcFromLength(){
 let fromLengthArray = Array.from({length: 10000}, (v, k) => k+1);
 console.log(fromLengthArray);
}
console.time('calcFromLength');
calcFromLength();
console.timeEnd('calcFromLength');

console.log('======== add a double for every item ========');

function loopDoubleArray(){
 var first5000Array = [...Array(5000+1).keys()].slice(1);
 var double5000Array =[];

 for(var i = 0; i< first500Array.length;++i){
   double5000Array.push(first5000Array[i]);
   double5000Array.push(first5000Array[i]);
 }
 console.log(double5000Array);
}
console.time('loopDoubleArray');
loopDoubleArray(); // Whatever is timed goes between the two "console.time"
console.timeEnd('loopDoubleArray');

function mapDoubleArray(){
 // adding 1,1,2,2,3,3 etc
 let doubleArray = [...Array(10000).keys()].map(x => Math.floor(++x/2) + x%2);
 console.log(doubleArray);
}
console.time('mapDoubleArray');
mapDoubleArray();
console.timeEnd('mapDoubleArray');

function fromDoubleArray(){
 let fromDoubleArray = Array.from({length: 10000}, (v, x) => Math.floor(++x/2) + x%2);
 console.log(fromDoubleArray);
}
console.time('fromDoubleArray');
fromDoubleArray(); // Whatever is timed goes between the two "console.time"
console.timeEnd('fromDoubleArray');

function doubleSpreadArray(){
 let keyArray = [...Array(500+1).keys()].slice(1);
 let doubleSpreadArray = [...keyArray,...keyArray];
 console.log(doubleSpreadArray);
}
console.time('doubleSpreadArray');
doubleSpreadArray(); // Whatever is timed goes between the two "console.time"
console.timeEnd('doubleSpreadArray');

function reduceDoubleArray(){
 let reduceDoubleArray = Array.from({length: 5000}, (v, k) => k+1).reduce((m,i) => m.concat([i,i]), []);
 console.log(reduceDoubleArray);
}
console.time('reduceDoubleArray');
reduceDoubleArray(); // Whatever is timed goes between the two "console.time"
console.timeEnd('reduceDoubleArray');
```

I compared some speeds and it looks as if there are not so many differences. The speed(in ms for 10000 items) of calculation between `map`, `slice` and `from` are not so different (slice one seems a bit better). Using reduce in the calculation for double items array is way more slower then the rest of methods

```
| mapMyArray     | 5,342041016 | 5,21484375  | 8,424804688 | 5,516113281 |
| sliceKeyArray  | 5,221191406 | 4,854248047 | 6,069091797 | 4,940185547 |
| calcFromLength | 6,156005859 | 5,988037109 | 6,031982422 | 6,739990234 |
```