# How to append multiple child elements to a div in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to append two `span`s to a `div` using the following code:

```
    d3.select("#breadcrumb")
            .append("span")
            .attr("class","breadcrumb-link")
            .text(d.name)
            .append("span")
            .text("/");
```

But this adds elements like:

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
    <span>
        <span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to add `span`s as siblings:

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
    <span>
    </span>

    <span>
    </span>
</div>
```

**I know this can be done by first selecting the `div` and then using 2 statements for each `span`.** Can I do this in a single chained statement?

Comment: you can append them if divs are not already defined in html or select it if div exists in html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending multiple non-nested elements for each data member with D3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485981/appending-multiple-non-nested-elements-for-each-data-member-with-d3-js)

Comment: @echonax Oh, sorry. But I think an answer for this one is also provided in that previous question. Should that be okay? http://stackoverflow.com/a/33809812/2036808

Comment: @Dar ah the 2nd one? Didn't see that one, my bad! Yes that's absolutely fine. I've added it to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**d3.js** is based on the idea of data-driven documents. That said, typically you'll have `data` as an `array` that you gonna **join** with a **selection**.

With that in mind you could try a simple hack by joining the selection `d3.select("#breadcrumb")` with an "artificial" array `[1, 2]`. This would look like this:

`d3.select("#breadcrumb").data([1, 2]).enter().append('span')...`

Note, the call of `enter()`.

If you wanna set different class attributes, you could stuff this data into the data array.